# Get-AzureAutomationJobOutput only returns 100 messages

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation, powershell-workflow

I'm using this:

```
$jobOutput = Get-AzureAutomationJobOutput -AutomationAccountName 'nonprodruntimebuild' -Id '1ca657d5-e9b6-4808-9386-40a88dd04271' -Stream "Any"
```

to get the job output based on a job Id.

However, it always returns an `Object[]` with 100 elements.
When I look at the history in the Azure portal, I can see there are 143 pages. Each page has 25 messages, so there should be 143*25=3575 messages.

I have tried this with different job Ids, and each time I still only get 100.

**Edit:** I have tried using `New-Object DateTime(2015,01,01)` for the StartTime parameter, but I still get 100 messages.

Comment: See if you can use `Reflect-CmdLet` against that command, and see if there is anything about the limit in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out 100 is the page size (constant). You need to use the -StartTime flag and specify a later time to get the next 100 messages.